# Removing elements in R vector to correspond with NAs in another R vector

Tags: r, vector, na

I have two vectors, say A and B

```
A <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
B <- c(6, NA, 8, 9, NA)
```

I would like to exclude elements in A corresponding to the elements of B which comprise NAs.

So, I am in need of an automatic way to remove indices 2 and 5 from both A and B, so that the length of both vectors is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use `is.na`

```
A[!is.na(B)]
#[1] 1 3 4
B[!is.na(B)]
#[1] 6 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
na.omit(cbind(A,B))
```